# Write a matrix that returns the position of the surrounding positions

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

Could someone point me in the write direction. I understand the problem conceptually but don't know how to implement.

Write a class MatrixNeighbors with the following fields:

```
int rows
int columns
int[][] matrix
```

the following constructor:

```
MatrixNeighbors(int rows, int columns) : sets both the rows and columns fields, then creates a new matrix of size [rows]x[columns].
```

and the following method:

```
String neighbors(int row, int column) : returns a String containing all the cell neighbors of the cell at row, column, starting directly above the specified cell and moving clockwise. If the cell is along any edge, be sure to omit the non-existent neighbors. See below for formatting.
Strings will be formatted as such: “<above cell row>,<above cell column>;<next cell clockwise row>,<next cell clockwise column>;…<last cell row>,<last cell column>;”.
```

Handle a nonexistent cell, one that exists outside of the matrix boundaries, by returning the string “cell does not exist”.

Consider the following diagram and code:

(0,0) (1,0) (2,0)

(0,1) (1,1) (2,1)

(0,2) (1,2) (2,2)

```
MatrixNeighbors m = new MatrixNeighbors(3, 3);
System.out.println(m.neighbors(0, 0)); //prints "0,1;1,1;1,0;"
System.out.println(m.neighbors(2, 2)); //prints "1,2;2,1;1,1;"
System.out.println(m.neighbors(1, 1)); //prints "0,1;0,2;1,2;2,2;2,1;2,0;1,0;0,0;"
System.out.println(m.neighbors(3, 0)); //prints "cell does not exist"
```

What I have:

```
public class MatrixNeighbors {
   int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    int [][] matrix;

    MatrixNeighbors(int row, int column) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MatrixNeighbors.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < MatrixNeighbors[i].length; j++)
                if (i <= row && j <= column) 
                    return (row - 1, column);

    }
```

I believe this is now returning the position of the spot one row above that one, but I don't know how to make sure it only returns it if that spot is inside the matrix and then how to return the spot to the right of the new spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use maths to determine who is around

- check if given point is within the matix
- check if top neighbour exists -> add to string
- check if right neighbour exists -> add to string
- print string

There is no quick function for this. That i am aware of

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check whether a position is valid by using a try-catch block. For example the following method uses try-catch to validate the position which is given to the method, and then checks whether the positions exist.
In all cases, try block will try to set a value to the position, if it throws an exception it means it doesn't exist so it's not added to the string. This will end up showing you the valid positions. It's the best way I've thought about, however I'm pretty sure there must be an easier method using a loop, but it's up to you to investigate.

```
public String neighbors(int row, int column)
{
    String ret = "";
    try
    {
         matrix[row][column] = 0; // To check if the row exists we just set a dummy value.
         try { matrix[row][column - 1] = 0; ret += row + "," + (column-1) + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row - 1][column - 1] = 0; ret += (row-1) + "," + (column-1) + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row - 1][column] = 0; ret += (row-1) + "," + column + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row - 1][column + 1] = 0; ret += (row-1) + "," + (column+1) + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row][column + 1] = 0; ret += row + "," + (column+1) + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row + 1][column + 1] = 0; ret += (row+1) + "," + (column+1) + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row + 1][column] = 0; ret += (row+1) + "," + column + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
         try { matrix[row + 1][column - 1] = 0; ret += (row+1) + "," + (column-1) + ";"; }
         catch (Exception e) {} 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ret += "Cell does not exist."; // Woho, exception caused due to position non-existing in matrix.
    }
    finally
    {
        return ret;
    }
}
```